# How to text/sms a chunk of text from a site to a phone?

Tags: sms, twilio, code-snippets

I want to take chunks of text from my site and allow people to text it to their phone. Similar to the "tweet this" buttons next to snippets of text, I am looking for a "text this to me" button.

Not looking for someone to do it for me, just point me in the direction. Is this something that can be accomplished with Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of web services out there, search SMS web services, you could talk to most of them direct via JS

```
http://www.twilio.com/sms
http://www.esendex.co.uk/service/web-sms
http://mashable.com/2008/04/19/send-text-messages.'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at Twilio, I'd start with their quickstart sms example, which uses PHP, though this should be able to be accomplished in just about any language of your choosing.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Answer (score 0):

[Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms%5Fgateway.php) is a popular SMS gateway. It works in 200+ countries.

Their API offers a choice of connection options via: HTTP/S, SMPP, SMTP, FTP, XML, SOAP, COM Object.

The HTTP/S method is as simple as this: `http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?to=NUMBER&msg=Message+Body+Here` ([Clickatell API Guide](http://support.clickatell.com/guides/clickatell/api_guide.php)).

The SMTP method consists of sending a plain-text e-mail to: `sms@messaging.clickatell.com`, with the following body:

```
user: xxxxx
password: xxxxx
api_id: xxxxx
to: 448311234567
text: Meet me at home
```

You can also test the gateway for free from your browser: "[Test SMS Gateway](http://www.clickatell.com/products/test_gateway.php)"